# Is this the right usage of "doubles down as"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

This is the sentence,

> While the apps primary purpose is to display websites but it also doubles down as a PDF reader.

Is the usage of "doubles down" correct?

Does double down mean have an addition purpose?

Comment: No; never.

"Double down" belongs solely to card games.

The obvious form of your example would be "While the app’s primary purpose is  (blah…), it doubles as (blah…)

“Double down” does not but “double” alone does mean “have an additional purpose”

Comment: While…but wrong, apps wrong, and double down wrong. If English is not your first language keep it simple (and it probably will turn out far better). "The app's primary purpose is to display websites but it can also serve as a PDF reader."

Answer (score 1):

Double down is primarily a card-playing term, specifically the game of "blackjack."
From [Merriam-Webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double%20down):

> 1 : to double the original bid in blackjack in exchange for only one
>   more card 2 : to become more tenacious, zealous, or resolute in a
>   position or undertaking

Thus, it doesn't really fit your use.
I think "doubles" would work for you, however.

From the same source: **double**

> 1 : having a twofold relation or character : DUAL

Comment: In that case would _While the apps primary purpose is to display websites but it also doubles up as a PDF reader_ be okay?

Comment: I think "doubles" would suffice: While the app's primary purpose is to display websites, it also doubles as a PDF reader.

Comment: No; never.

"Double down" is only ever used in card games.

Is the usage of "doubles down" correct? Extremely unlikely.

Does double down mean have an addition purpose? No.; never.

"Double down" and "double up" *appear* logically relevant, but they are not. They share the word "double"; so what?

If you really wish to look at "… it also doubles down as a PDF reader" then please parse every word of that.

The only problem was that you used "doubles down" when clearly what you meant was "doubles", with neither "down" nor any other qualification?

Answer (score 0):

It is a figurative usage of the card game idiom:

***[Double down:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/double+down)***

> (By extension,) to significantly increase or strengthen effort, investment, or resolve toward some goal, strategy, or action so as to maximize the potential yield as a result.
>
> - The president made clear that he intends to double down the government's involvement in the war overseas.
> - With the market booming, ***many companies are doubling down their development in mobile apps and games.***

(Farlex Dictionary of Idioms)